# Pick a random line from a text file and store it in a variable (Python 3)

Tags: variables, random, python-3.2

I am trying to code a program which reads a file, which will contain many words (one word per line), then selects a random line (word) from the file, so I am able to store it in a variable for me to use later on.

I don't really know where to start as I am not very experienced. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried?. There is a command line (in a console) called [shuf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuf) that does exactly what you describe.

Comment: @BinaryZebra not really tried anything, but the answer I've just been given seemed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first you will need to open the file
`file = open('filename.txt', 'w')`

Then you need to read the file you can read each line into a list by doing `words = file.readlines` (this can also be done with a loop or in a number of other ways)

Then you can use the random module to generate a random number and get the word from that index in the words list. Then just store that word to a variable.

There are other ways of doing this but this is one of the easiest.